# Why isn't dplyr filter() properly filtering out blanks found in two columns?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Am I doing something wrong with the logic here? See below:

```
nrow(contractors_fy20)
```

[1] 59190

```
y <- contractors_fy20 %>% filter(recipient_name == "" & recipient_parent_name == "")
nrow(y)
```

[1] 1

This appears to be accurate.

```
x <- contractors_fy20 %>% filter(recipient_name != "" & recipient_parent_name != "")
nrow(x)
```

[1] 58952

Why is it removing a thousand rows when it should only be removing one?

Comment: Use the `|` instead of `&`

Comment: Negate your original condition - `contractors_fy20 %>% filter(!(recipient_name == "" & recipient_parent_name == ""))`

Answer (score 1):

The first condition checks when both are blank.  In the second case, it is only checking when both are non-blank.  Instead, it should be either one of them as non-blank, as this will also include the cases where both are non-blank

```
x <- contractors_fy20 %>% 
         filter(recipient_name != "" | recipient_parent_name != "")
```

---

Consider the below example

```
x1 <- c("", 'a', 'b', "", "")
x2 <- c("a", "", "a", "", "b")
```

Checking when both are blank.  It is only the 4th element

```
x1 == "" & x2 == ""
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Check if both are non-blank, and it is only the third element

```
x1 != "" & x2 != ""
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

The OR (`|`) will be TRUE when either one of them is non-blank

```
x1 != "" | x2 != ""
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

the total is 5 in length and now we have 4 TRUE